# Изменение параметров Button

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-layout

У меня есть три `Button`, которые меняют значение `layout_margin`, через программный код. Все проходит успешно, но обновление кнопок не происходит! Вот обработчик (думаю тут все понятно):

```
public void onClickTab(View view) {
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_btn2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_btn3);

    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.actionbar_btn1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "btn1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button2);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn2.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(3, 0, 3, 3);
        btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 3);
        break;
    case R.id.actionbar_btn2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "btn2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 3);
        btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button2);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn2.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(3, 0, 3, 0);
        btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 3);
        break;
    case R.id.actionbar_btn3:
        Toast.makeText(this, "btn3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 3);
        btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn2.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(3, 0, 3, 3);
        btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button2);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Если ставить setContentMenu — программа не работает :. Как менять этот параметр `margin` и обновлять `View`, чтобы было видно изменение (я придумал только создать 3 фрагмента с нужными параметрами...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

1. Получить `LayoutParams`
2. Что-нить с ними сделать. (присвоить `margin` в вашем случае)
3. Присвоить их элементу разметки.

   ```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams();
   params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
   btn3.setLayoutParams(params);
   ```